# Is there any way to send a message to email in html

Tags: html, css, forms, email, message

I am making a form right now and i have a bit of a problem. HTML doesn`t support mail-sendings without a downloaded email program. But is there maybe a way to not just send an email but send a message instead that can be converted to email? Is there any service out there that supports this idea? I know that PHP would be the solution, but i only have access to a HTML/CSS only server. Please help me out.

Comment: You cant send message/email with only html/css.

Comment: @Leothelion Which is _exactly_ what the OP already stated himself.

Comment: @arkascha yes but he was asking with html/css only and not mail but message so i confirm that even you can't send message too.

Comment: Since you do need some form of an active component and in your situation server side scripting is not available you have to use client side scripting, so javascript. It certainly should be possible to send an email message by means of javascript, but it would be insecure, since you'd have to enclose your sender credentials into the script. That would allow anyone to use your account for whatever purpose they feel motivated for...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an iframe for this. But you would still have to get a php file. However, you will have to host it from somewhere else. Maybe google drive? Or smth like that.

Answer (score -1):

Not as far as I know, but if the website user has Gmail binded to the "mailto:" protocol there's no need for an installed software, it will redirect him/her to Gmail with the email address of the recipient already filled in

Comment: Which still is not a usable solution, because still many users will have a non working form.

Comment: Indeed, there's basically no difference from having a dedicated software installed, just pointing out there's no need for the latter

Comment: Well, not everyone not using a real email software uses the gmail service. There are far better email service providers than google...